# View and hide columns in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with values in columns B:G. In the same sheet in cell A1 I have made a drop down list using data validation with values like A, B and C.

What I require is when I select cell value A then columns B:C need to be visible and the other columns should be hidden from D:G. In the same way if I select B from the list I need to view columns D:E and B:C and F:G should be hidden.

Could you please help me on this.

Note: I don't have good knowledge in VBA.

Comment: You need a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` routine. Look that up and try to create the macro you need. Come back with a question if you run into difficulties.  Note: a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` routine needs to be in the worksheet's code area. You may also need to search for "Excel VBA events" for background information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open the VBA editor (`ALT + F11`)
2. Double click `Sheet1`
3. Select `Worksheet` in the top left drop down and `Change` in the top right hand drop down
4. Paste this code

NB- this assumes data validation is in cell `A1`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim allColumns As Range

    Set allColumns = Columns("B:G")
    allColumns.Hidden = True

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "A" Then
            Columns("B:C").Hidden = False
        ElseIf Target.Value = "B" Then
            Columns("D:E").Hidden = False
        ElseIf Target.Value = "C" Then
            //Add more logic here
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's Working! Thank you Alex. Expecting your valuable support in future.

Answer (score 3):

Go to view --> macros.
Hit the dropdown and do "record new macro".
Right click on a column header and do hide column.
Then do unhide column.
Do Macros->stop recording.
Macros-->View macros
Click edit.

you get the following code:

```
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

Now you know how to hide and show columns.  First you select the column then your set Hidden = true or false.

Google:  excel macro when cell value changes

Click the first link:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612

Take the code from that link and read the comments:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

**Make sure you read the link very closely. And follow the instructions.  I find I sometimes rush and miss important details**

Let me know if this is enough or you need more help.

Comment: Derek, Thanks for your reply.will confirm you the status shortly

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but it may still be useful to someone.
*Userform to hide-unhide worksheet’s columns :*

The userform that we created to hide the columns in the workbook and unhide the hidden columns contains also a button to minimize userform. With to the drop-down list in the userform can be navigated between worksheets, the selected worksheet from the combobox is active and the column management(hide-unhide) of this worksheet is provided.

[image]

[Explanations and sample Excel file here](https://eksi30.com/excel-hide-unhide-columns-using-userform/)